# Working with Gaussian filter in frequency domain + Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I read about Gaussian filter in frequency domain, but there is some points I can't understand here:

1. Will the Gaussian filter is always a square matrix?
2. If 1's answer is yes, what will happen if my image is a rectangle matrix? In Matlab, I read the image, then use `fft2` to convert it from spatial domain to frequency domain, then I used `ffshift` to centralize it. What I want is multiply the frequency domain matrix of image to the Gaussian filter matrix, then converting the result to spatial domain by using `ifft2`, but because of different size of Gaussian filter matrix and frequency domain matrix of image, they can't be multiplied together. (I'm not using `conv2` and `fspectial` here).

Comment: Well, a gaussian filter is usually defined in a square grid due to its isotropy, but nothing prevents you to crop it to a rectangle, circle, star, you name it. Now, more commonly, you can define proper paddings to match both support regions.

Comment: why won't you use `conv2(image,guassian,'same')` ?

Answer (score 1):

A Guassian filter is in fact circular since it is a function of the distance from its center. A rectangle matrix is used because it is more convenient.
What you can do in order to overcome the size differences is to zero-pad the filter:

```
img = imread( imgFileName ); % read image, use gray-level images here.
IMG = fft2( img ); % Fourier of img
sz = size( img );
h = fspecial( 'gaussian', sz, sigma ); % create a filter with std sigma same size as img
H = fft2( h ); % Fourier of filter
F = IMG.*H; % filter in Fourier space
f = ifft2( F ); % back to spatial domain.
```